# How to stop repeatetive google notification response from google check out

Tags: google-checkout

I am  integrate google checkout for payment.every thing going in perfect way,but at last
 in response handler,response of order coming repetitively. i  had try  to many things but i unable to find that how to stop "repetitively response. "
                                                         because of this size of file
**'googlemessage.log'** increases every time.

```
                             $Gresponse->SendAck(null, false);
```

but this can's help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to acknowledge each notification with a HTTP 200 response code and the serial number of the notification:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API.html#responding_to_notifications

Google Checkout will try to resend the notification for up to 14 days or until you acknowledge it.

Comment: Hello Mihai Ionescu,thanks for your suggestion. i was all ready  read this link but it can' help me.actually i was using this code in response handler
case "new-order-notification": {     
      $Gresponse->SendAck($data[$root]['serial-number'], true);
break;}
i also use every where we  use sendAck() function.